# Pushing objects in an array only returns last object pushed in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**I Know this question to be duplicated, but none of the other answers worked for me...**
I am trying to push objects to my array using the onChnage method. But every time my array returns the last value, not the full value. I tried so many times to fix this issue. But I can't.

```
function addVariantSection(data) {
    const handleChecked = (id) => (e) => {
      const tempData1=[];
      const { checkedID } = e.target;
      const vID = e.currentTarget.id.split('-', 1);
      tempData1.push({ productId:itemID, variantId:vID})
      setChecked((values) => ({ ...values, [id]: checkedID, }));
      setVariant([...tempData1]); // variant always give the last value.
    };
    return (
      <Grid key={data._id} container spacing={10}>
        <Grid item xs={12} style={{ justifyContent: 'space-between', display: 'flex' }}>
          <div>{`${data.variant1}-${data.variant2}`}</div>
          {/* eslint-disable-next-line no-useless-concat */}
          <Checkbox id={`${data._id}-` + `checkData`} color="primary" checked={checked[data._id]} onChange={handleChecked(data._id)} />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overwriting `setVariant` with the array - `tempData1`. So you need to preserve the previous value of `setVariant` to get the complete array you are expecting.

So do this instead

```
setVariant((prev) => ([...prev, ...tempData1]));
```

Your function will look like this:

```
const handleChecked = (id) => (e) => {
    const tempData1=[];
    const { checkedID } = e.target;
    const vID = e.currentTarget.id.split('-', 1);
    tempData1.push({ productId:itemID, variantId:vID})
    setChecked((values) => ({ ...values, [id]: checkedID, }));
    setVariant((prev) => ([...prev, ...tempData1]));
};
```

Comment: It's work. Thank you very much, sir...If I want to delete some array, How can I do this with this function...Can you help me with that too? I am still a student and still learning things. Thank you very much for your time, sir.

Comment: @Zenixo If you want to remove then use filter method on that array "variant" and remove that particular item using the condition. Please explore more on "filter" and you will know it.

Answer (score 1):

You are simply setting the value of variant as a new array here, which is going to have `tempData1`:

```
setVariant([...tempData1]);
```

Firstly you need the previous value of variant, so the callback pattern for setState is going to be useful. It gives **a reliable value for the previous state always**.
And using spread `...`, simply append the new object at the end.

```
const handleChecked = (id) => (e) => {
      const { checkedID } = e.target;
      const vID = e.currentTarget.id.split('-', 1);
      setChecked((values) => ({ ...values, [id]: checkedID, }));
      setVariant((variant) => { return [...variant,{ productId:itemID, variantId:vID}]}); // variant always give the last value.
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers above should be ok, but if you don't want the format where you put a function inside a `setState` what you can do is:

```
const [variant, setVariant] = useState([]);

.
.
.

setVariant([...variant, ...tempData1]);
```